# $\varinjlim R/(r) = \mathrm{Frac}(R)/R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a PID. Is it true that 
$$
\varinjlim R/(r) = \mathrm{Frac}(R)/R
$$
where the direct system is given by $R/(r_{1}r_{2}) \xrightarrow{\times r_{2}} R/(r_{1})$? This is true for $R = \mathbb{Z}$. I tried to define a map $$\mathrm{Frac}(R)\to \varinjlim R/(r)$$ whose kernel is $R$, but I failed.

Comment: Map $a/b$ to $a\in R/(b)$.

Comment: What is $Frac(R)/R$ ?